# CCLog with System Time like NSLog

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

For checking efficiency of code I need to know time taken in execution of code.With NSlog is easy to know as it shows time up to ms.How can i achieve this through CClog

Example NSLog

```
 2013-12-03 10:11:58.091 xxxx[12786:c07] START....
 2013-12-03 10:12:04.281 xxxx
```

In CCLog just

```
 Cocos2d:
```

Comment: Here is the answer...[LINK](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/40276?r=40315)

Answer (score 1):

In CCCommon.mm

Replace this...

```
void CCLog(const char * pszFormat, ...)

{

    printf("Cocos2d: ");
    char szBuf[kMaxLogLen+1] = {0};
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, pszFormat);
    vsnprintf(szBuf, kMaxLogLen, pszFormat, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    printf("%s", szBuf);
    printf("\n");
}
```

To this...

```
void CCLog(const char * pszFormat, ...)

{

    //printf("Cocos2d: ");
    char szBuf[kMaxLogLen+1] = {0};
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, pszFormat);
    vsnprintf(szBuf, kMaxLogLen, pszFormat, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    //printf("%s", szBuf);
    //printf("\n");

    NSLog(@"%s", szBuf);
}
```

Comment: Seems outdated. Any recent info? Using cocos2d-x 3.5